# rails saving recognized link from text to database with rinku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a rails app with chat. In the chat for the messages I use rinku gem to recognize links which works well. On the top of this I would like to save the links as message.link without the rest of the text around it from the message.body.
So for example in the code below the user sent the message.body "hi there www.stackoverflow.com" and I would like to save only the "www.stackoverflow.com" as message.link. How can I do that?

view

```
<p><%= find_links(message.body) %></p>
```

controller

```
def find_links(message_body)
  Rinku.auto_link(message_body, mode=:all, 'target="_blank"', skip_tags=nil).html_safe 
end
```

it will appear in the DOM as:

```
<p>hey there <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/" target="_blank">http://stackoverflow.com/</a></p>
```

and will appear in the db as message.body:

```
"hey there http://stackoverflow.com/"
```

UPDATE:

messages controller

```
require "uri"

def create
  .....
  if message.save
    link = URI.extract(message.body)
    update_attribute(message.link = link)
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need regular expression to identify URLs from text. Try following regular expression:

```
/(https?:\/\/(?:www\.|(?!www))[^\s\.]+\.[^\s]{2,}|www\.[^\s]+\.[^\s]{2,})/
```

Working demo: http://rubular.com/r/bHQdFHZYFH

```
2.1.2 :001 > str = "hey hi hello www.google.com https://stackoverflow.com http://tech-brains.blogspot.in"
2.1.2 :002 > regexp = /(https?:\/\/(?:www\.|(?!www))[^\s\.]+\.[^\s]{2,}|www\.[^\s]+\.[^\s]{2,})/
2.1.2 :003 > str.scan(regexp)

 => [["www.google.com"], ["https://stackoverflow.com"], ["http://tech-brains.blogspot.in"]]
```

Comment: RAJ, what is the difference between your and Veets solution? Which one works better once the link is already recognized by rinku?

Comment: Veets solution won't work for many other ways of writing URL links e.g.: www.google.com

Comment: RAJ I see, how can I call this on the message.body?

Comment: You need to do like `stringObj.match(/regex/)`… I am commenting from my phone, later on I will update answer for you.

Comment: RAJ, sry I had to deal with other problems, but I'm back to this project now. Have you updated your answer?

Comment: No probelm. I had updated the answer, however,I assume your problem got resolved as I can see accepted answer.

Comment: RAJ, is it possible to have the result as ["www.google.com", "http:.....] instead of  [["www.google.com"], ["http:...]] ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Ruby code:

```
2.0.0-p247 :001 > require "uri"
 => true 
2.0.0-p247 :002 > URI.extract("hey there http://stackoverflow.com/")
 => ["http://stackoverflow.com/"]
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Veets, what do you think about my update? Is it a good solution?

Comment: `update_attribute(message.link = link)` will add an array to the database column with all the links from message body. If you expect the message body to have more than one links then you are good to go ahead with the code.

But if you are sure that the message body will always have only one link then you might want to update the code as `update_attribute(message.link = link[0])`

Comment: I wanna save all the links but not within one message object, so I create new message object where body will be empty or create a link model that belongs to conversation or message (conversation is one given chat with 2 users who can send messages to each other --> message belongs_to convers. and convers. has_many messages/has_one recipient and has_one sender). What do you think what I should choose here? So 1. save as message.link where body will be empty 2. new link model belongs to message 3. new link model belongs to conversation? P.S: My goal is to sort all the links between 2 users.